# Internationalization broken in Ploneboard?

Tags: plone

I'm using Plone 4.1.4. I added the Ploneboard product in my buildout. Everything work as expected, save the translations for Ploneboard; the product is stuck in english, even as everything else is in french. I do see all the .po file in the /buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Ploneboard-3.2-py2.6.egg/Products/Ploneboard/i18n/ directory.

Does the translation system changed in Plone 4.x ? Must we configure something else ?

Best,

Christian

Comment: I can't confirm that, at least not with Ploneboard 3.0. Do you use Linguaplone?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem with folder permissions, and Plone may not be able to compile the translations at startup.

You can start your Plone instance in fg mode (./instance fg) and look if there's any WARNING message related to ploneboard i18n folder.

If this is a folder permission issue, try to stop your instance and run this command:

```
chown -R plone:root <installation_dir>/buildout-cache/eggs
```

Reference: [Fixing common Plone errors](http://howto.biapy.com/en/development/plone-1/configuration/fixing-common-plone-errors) (Fix the translation compilation warnings at Zope / Plone start)